# CakePHP 3.x - assets add version instead of timestamp

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I know that CakePHP comes with the option to add the timestamp at the end of the assets file for them to be cached, but I want to find the best practice to include instead of timestamp the version and to use it only for some css and js files.

What I had in my mind is to create a helper function which will append the version to the filename but this means that I need to change a lot of files which are included in the page.

Comment: How will your helper know the version number of each file?

Comment: I have a global application version defined in the config files.

Comment: You will never update your CSS or JS without also updating the application version? And you're okay with people getting "new" copies of these files whenever the application version is updated, regardless of whether the individual files changed? If the answer to either of these is no, then you'll need timestamps, and this is why they're the usual solution. If the answer to both is yes, then you might extend the HTML helper, overriding just the relevant functions to append the version when one of the specific files you want this on is requested, then passing it on to the parent implementation.